# How do i create a article with tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table, grid-layout

im working on a html newsletter right now and since i can only use tables to make it as responsive as possible, i stumbled upon some problems.

Im loading Articles from an RSS Feed and displaying it with (Image on Left, Title uper right and summary below.) It works perfectly fine with css but now with tables it seems impossible ;/ Thats how far i got.

It looks pretty good for the  beginning but when the title is longer than 1 row it moves my image also 1 row further.

```html
<table style="font-family: Helvetica,arial, sans-serif;">
 <col width="130">
 <col width="250">
  <tr style="vertical-align:top;">
    <th valign="right" style="text-align:left; color:white;">Überschrift</th>
 <th valign="right" style="text-align:left;">
 <!--#html name="title" #-->
 Im the Title
 <!--#/html#-->
 </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> 
 <!--#image name="image" #-->
 <img src="" style="width:300px; height:300px; object-fit:cover;">
 <!--#/image#-->
 </td>
 <td valign="top" style="height: 100px; font-size: 13px; color: #333333; line-height: 20px; ">
 <!--#html name="description" #-->
 Im a Summary
 <!--#/html#-->
 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to have the title and the image in the same row?

Comment: which type  article you want